# I am trying to make an API using spring boot and MongoDB. How should my entity class be for following template

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, api

I am trying to make an API using spring boot and MongoDB.
How should my entity class be for following template
I'm trying to have data in this format

```
{
"cart_id":"string",
"customer_name":"string"
"total_value":"double",
"line_items":
  {
    "product_name":"string",
    "quantity":"number",
    "price":"double"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an entity class like

```
@Data // lombok
@Document(collection="cart") //cart is your collection name
public class Cart {

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private String custname;
    private double totval;
    private LineItems line_items;
}
```

Create another class LineItems

```
@Data

public class LineItems {
    
    private String prodname;
    private int quant;
    private int price;

}
```